# Fast algorithms for long sequences of sparse matrix products multiplying a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, computational-mathematics, sparse-matrices

**Context:** Having worked with developing algorithms involving huuge linear least squares systems involving sparse matrices, so far I have mostly constructed these huge sparse matrices explicitly and then solved using Krylov subspace methods. For various reasons of flexibility and memory optimization I am now investigating possibility of having sparse matrices more loosely coupled and calculating matrix-vector products without accumulating one big sparse matrix.

So to the question: Given that I have a sequence of sparse matrices $${\bf M}_1,\cdots, {\bf M}_k$$, and I want to calculate the matrix-vector product $$\left(\prod_{\forall k} {\bf M}_k\right){\bf v} = {\bf M}_1 \cdot {\bf M}_2 \cdots {\bf M}_k \cdot {\bf v}$$ in one go e.g. without matrix-matrix multiplication and without having to store the intermediate results in vectors (as memory reads and writes often are slow for computers compared to calculations).

Comment: "without having to store the intermediate results in vectors" seems an impossible requirement. And when read/writes are confined to the cache, they are not specially slow.

Comment: What are the matrix sizes ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust for most of my applications typically $n\times n$ in the range $10^5<n<10^7$ and $1-9$ non-zero elements each row. Often convolution operations on image data or vector fields, diagonal weight matrices and such.

Comment: But what is the sparsity of the product matrix ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust if multiplied together I think the whole product matrix has $5-25$ non-zero elements each row depending on application. But the thing is I want to make decisions to easily and dynamically replace matrices without having to recalculate the whole matrix.

Comment: The ratio of the sparsities leaves little room for large $k$. But your last requirement just leaves no choice.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but there is some structure that I could possibly further exploit. Often products are of the normal equation form $M^T D M$ with $D$ diagonal.

Comment: Obviously, $DM$ can be applied in a single go. But $M^T$ has probably little relation with $M$ as regards the sparse representation.

Comment: It will be hard to beat repeated sparse matvecs with the matrices in CSR format

Comment: @NickAlger: with the reported sparsity properties, it is not even sure that repeated "matvecs" will be faster at all... (but the OP didn't say anything about $k$).

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea what a matvec is. I am writing my completely own library over here. I am quite sure some data structure could be invented that could improve the speed of such a product, at least for limited $k$ and matrices of some known-beforehand structure, like diagonal or block-diagonal or diagonal blocks and so on.

Comment: Matvec is just shorthand for "matrix-vector product". The standard approach would be to put each of the matrices $M_i$ into CSR/Yale sparse matrix format, then perform the matrix vector multiplications one at a time, e.g., $M_1(M_2(M_3 v))$. I'm just saying that this may be pretty fast, even though it is basic.

Comment: @NickAlger Ah. Okay. Yep doing one matrix-vector multiplication at a time is pretty fast, at least in my lib, but I think it could get even faster if we could fuse the sparse factors with some clever data structure and do two or three or maybe more in one go.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep all initial matrices, assuming a sparsity factor $\sigma$ for each, iterating the $k$ matrix/vector multiplies will cost $k\sigma n^2$ in total. This is to be compared to the cost with a "huge matrix", $\Sigma n^2$, hence a key factor is the degradation of sparsity, $\Sigma\leftrightarrow k\sigma$.

Also note that the amount of coefficients to be read are in the same ratio ($\Sigma n^2\leftrightarrow k\sigma n^2$) and this can seriously impact the running time due to cache or virtual memory effects (on the other hand, reading/writing the $n$ vector elements $k$ times should not be significant).

Comment: Yes I also think cache should handle this if I have stored the intermediate matrices smartly in memory. Maybe I should double check if I do that. Thank you for contribution.